# Remove div tag using BeautifulSoup but keep contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Using Python/BeautifulSoup I would like to just remove an outer div tag but retain it's contents.

So starting with this:

```
<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

Would end up like this.

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

I feel like this should be simple but can't find a way to do it..

Comment: OK, I can see this should be quite easy with unwrap:
soup.div.unwrap()
The problem is that in my script I get :
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unwrap'

Comment: Actually, I tried with `soup.div.unwrap()`. And it's working.

Comment: @f00b - that's a completely different problem than your original question, you should probably make a new post. It means the parser can't find your DIV for some reason. (My guess is if you're parsing the HTML fragment above verbatim, BS automatically could be adding \<html>, <body> etc around it to make it a valid document.)

Comment: @millimoose is right. If you're using `lxml` parser, it does add the `<html><body>` tags. You could either use `soup.find('div')` or change the parser to `html.parser`. But, I would recommend the first change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) function as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.div.unwrap()
print(soup)
```

The would display:

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

If `lxml` is used, it would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
soup.div.unwrap()
print(soup)
```

Giving you:

```html
<html><body>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
</body></html>
```